# Trigger dropdown change automatically in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have two dropdowns (`country` and `state`) which are cascading. When I select country, then `state` dropdown dynamically filled by states of **selected** country. I want set `country` and `state`. But, I don't want write  `this.onSelect(2);` row. I want do automatically. How can I do this? **Or, what is the recomended way for this?**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v55qki?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since your data filling logic is in `onSelect` you have to invoke at some point to get initial values.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzzstx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Either move filtering to service to `getState(countryId)` so you will be able to filter it out tight away in the init, or leave it like it is. Its not that bad.

This is an example - code is quite clear here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9len3v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I don't like the fact that you are juggling with IDs instead of actual objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Antoniossss . Your second example working perfectly. But first example not working. It is not setting `state` combobox in first example.

Comment: Double check because it works initially and after you select country.

Comment: I checked again. But when I go to your first link, `state` combobox is `Sao Paulo`. But, it must be `Minas Gerais`. @Antoniossss

Comment: change initial value then

Comment: I could't understand how first stackblitz work :) But your second example is working perfectly for me. It solved my issue. Thanks a lot @Antoniossss

Comment: @Antoniossss : How to trigger onSelect(countryid) when i patch the form in edit mode. Now I need to manually call this function to update the dropdown values.

Here is your forked example of my problem : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ft9zw1

Comment: @RenilBabu just dont bind to select onSelecect but rahter to cotrol `valueChanges` stream